# EXcel filtering with multiple different types of criteria

Tags: excel

I'm trying to work out a value (no. of 'dropdowns' - in yellow highlight) for multiple people, based on multiple criteria (including some data and excluding other data). Would anyone have an idea of how to get started on this?
The description in the image sets out the criteria.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: The image should be a visual representation of the data and expected output, we prefer markdown tables so we can copy paste.  All descriptions of the problem should be text in the body of the question.

Comment: You could try this: `=BYROW(H17:H21,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(FILTER(P2:P14,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(H2:H14&"|"&P2:P14&"|"&RIGHT(M2:M14),TOCOL("PCK ORDER"&"|"&x&{"|A","|B","|C","|D"})))*(Q2:Q14>=DATE(F2,D2,B2))*(Q2:Q14<=DATE(F3,D3,B3))*(ISNA(XMATCH(M2:M14,U2:U4))),"")<>""))))`

Comment: Are you looking for the counts? the above formula would do, but I am not clear actually